# How to initialise Firebase in Flutter for IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I want to initialised firebase for IOS. For receiving push notification in my Flutter App.

```
  if (Platform.isAndroid)
    {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(),
    }
```

For Android I am using this method for initialising the firebase. I can't understand how it implement for IOS. When ever it is used same as for the IOS is shows errors.

```
void main() async => {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(),
      if (Platform.isAndroid)
        {
          await Firebase.initializeApp(),
        },
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
          .then((_) {
        runApp(new MyApp());
      })
    };
```

No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core

Answer (score 0):

Have you try what they say in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)?

```
  if (Platform.isAndroid)
    {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();// add this line
      await Firebase.initializeApp(),
    }
```

Comment: WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(),

      if (Platform.isAndroid)

        {
          await Firebase.initializeApp(),
        },
 Yes its work fine with Android. And I also get notifications in Android Decive. But how it work for IOS?

Comment: Have a look on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542308/flutter-on-ios-despite-calling-firebase-initializeapp-on-a-future-builder-ap/69543045?noredirect=1#comment122920280_69543045

Comment: Please help me i am confusing today is my project submission date. I Updated my above code section

Comment: Even like this : Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}

Comment: the contructor in MyApp: const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

Comment: MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core))
Sowing me the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238094/discussion-between-wasiq-hussain-and-mario-francois).